# Convergence of infinite series

Tags: real-analysis

$(c_k)$ is real number sequence. It is known that $\lim_{y\to 1^-}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k y^k $ exists. Moreover, $\lim_{k\to \infty} kc_k=0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_ky^k$ exists for all $y \in [0,1)$.Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^n kc_k=0$

ٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍSuppose that for every $y \in (0,1)$ we take G(y), which is a natural number and depends on y, such that $$ G(y) \leq \frac{1}{1-y} \leq 1+G(y) .$$

I want to prove that $\lim_{y\to 1^-}\sum_{k=1}^{G(y)} c_k(1-y^k) =0$. Then finally I want to prove that $\lim_{y\to 1^-}\sum_{k=1}^{G(y)} c_k=\lim_{y\to1^-} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_ky^k$.

I tried the following:

For $0\leq y < 1$, the sequence $(y_n)$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded, and therefore the Abel test can be used . Then, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{2n}y^{2n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{2n-1}y^{2n-1}$ are convergent due to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}y^{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{2n}y^{2n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{2n-1}y^{2n-1}$. But then I feel something is wrong.
I am confused. I want to do it using elementary analysis. Please help!

Comment: Your question is really good, though it cannot be classified as research level, which is the fundamental topic discussed in this Q&A site. Try to post it at our sister site [Math.SE](https//math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What you want to prove follows from some basic Tauberian theorems (by Hardy, Landau, Lttlewood, Karamata, for your choice). See the first chapter of Korevaar's book on Tauberian theory, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the following asymptotic expansion holds for $x\simeq0$ 
$$
(x+1)^k-1=kx+\mathcal{O}(x^2).
$$ 
Using the above with $x=1-y$ and recalling that $G(y)\simeq (1-y)^{-1}$, we get for $y\simeq 1$ 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{G(y)}c_k(1-y^k)=(1-y)\sum_{k=1}^{G(y)}k c_k+\mathcal{O}\left((1-y)^2 \sum_{k=1}^{G(y)} c_k\right)=(1-y)\sum_{k=1}^{G(y)}k c_k+\mathcal{O}\left(1-y\right).
$$
Noticing that as $y\rightarrow 1^{-}$ the first term on the right hand side behaves like
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}n \sum_{k=1}^n k c_k=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} kc_k=0
$$
we finally get
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow 1^{-}}\sum_{k=1}^{G(y)}c_k(1-y^k)=0.
$$
From it follows that
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow 1^{-}}\sum_{k=1}^{G(y)}c_k=\lim_{y\rightarrow 1^{-}}\sum_{k=1}^{G(y)}c_k y^k,
$$
due to the assumption that $\lim_{y\rightarrow 1^{-}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k y^k$ exists.